# Upload multiple files and save in database laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my controller code:

```
$images = Input::file('images');


foreach($images as $image){

    $filenames = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '-' .  $image->getClientOriginalName();

     $imageFolder = 'clients';
     $image->move($imageFolder , $filenames);

    echo $filenames;
}
```

I was trying to upload multiple image files and could do that. Now I want to save all the file names as an array or as whatever is the best in the database.

I tried to use `serialize()` laravel 4.2 says serialization is not allowed for uploading.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to save the file names to the database, why don't you use a simple `DB::table('files')->insert(array('filename' => $filenames));` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
$images = Input::file('images');

$filenames = array();

foreach($images as $image){

   $filenames [] = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '-' .  $image->getClientOriginalName();

   $imageFolder = 'clients';
   $image->move($imageFolder , $filenames);

   echo $filenames;
}
```

Comment: strrpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in */vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:133